# How do I run this code when the current day's date is equal to the date I set in the variable?

Tags: python, email, date, datetime

I am trying to send an email when the current date is equal to the date of the variable.

```
import smtplib


import datetime

date = datetime

fromaddr = "holidaysandspecialdates@gmail.com"
toaddrs  = 'noah.s.cha@gmail.com'
msg = input("Enter your message:")


# Credentials (if needed)
username = ''
password = ''

date = 2015-5-24

when datetime.date.today() == date:
    fromaddr = "holidaysandspecialdates@gmail.com"
    toaddrs  = 'noah.s.cha@gmail.com'
    msg = "CodeDay Ends Today!!!"
# The actual mail send
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
print("Your message:" + "'" + msg + "'" + " has been sent to " + toaddrs + "."  )
```

Comment: If that was a real password, you should change it immediately. Even after anmol's helpful edit, the information is still in the edit history of the question (and could have already been cached by search engines).

Comment: There's no `when` statement in Python, and it's not clear what you legal statement you _wanted_ there. Plus, `date = 2015-5-24` just sets it to `1986`, so the `==` will never be true; if you want to construct a `date` object, you have to do some explicitly—e.g., `datetime.date(2015, 5, 24)`.

Comment: How must one handle such scenarios(questions having personal credentials) @abarnert

Comment: The only reasonable thing to do is to change the password of the account.

Comment: @anmol_uppal: I think what you did is the best thing possible to reduce the harm. But there's only so much you can do; beyond that, it's up to the OP to change his password (and make sure nobody did anything on his account before he got to it).

Comment: @anmol_uppal: in principle, [one could also flag the question to delete the revision with sensitive info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132120/137096)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But I haven't earned the privilege of closing a question with my raised flag.

Comment: @anmol_uppal: Just click "flag" on a question/comment/answer, and choose the flag reason "in need of moderator intervention" (or "other", if that's not there); that always means a moderator will deal with it manually, and you can do that at low rep. In this case, I wouldn't do it (he really has to change the password even if you get the revision deleted, and once he's changed the password there's no harm in the revision being there, right?), but it's worth knowing how.

Comment: guys the password was not real...

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're looking for is a way for the program to start up, then wait until the date is 2015-5-25, then send out a message.

The easy way to do that is with some external scheduler—`cron`, `launchd`, `Scheduled Tasks`, or whatever your operating system comes with. Just set it up to run your program once, as early as possible on that date. (If you can't figure out how to do that, you'll probably want to AskUbuntu, AskDifferent, etc., depending on what platform you're on.)

---

If you really want to do this inside Python, you can. What you need is a way to *go to sleep* until 2015-5-25. To do that, you use the `sleep` function. But you need to know how many seconds to sleep.

```
import datetime
import time

target = datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 25)
time_to_sleep = target - datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(time_to_sleep.total_seconds())
```

Notice that I created an actual `date` object out of 2015-5-25; just using `2015-5-25` in your code is asking it to subtract 5 from 2015, then subtract 25 from the result, so you get the integer 1986, not a date. (Also, I used `datetime` instead of `date`, so it'll sleep until the start of 2015-5-25, not until some arbitrary time in the middle of the day.)

Anyway, the big problem with doing it this way is that your program has to sit there, doing nothing, for days. If someone accidentally reboots your computer and doesn't restart the program, it will never do anything. Your system scheduler has a way to solve that problem (the system automatically restarts it every time it turns on, and it immediately checks all the scheduled tasks to make sure it didn't miss any of them), but you don't (unless you want to make this program run every time your system turns on until the end of time). There are also a variety of smaller problems (see J.F. Sebastian's comments for a few), which, again, your system scheduler already knows how to work around, but which will either take a lot more work or be impossible for you to deal with.

Comment: Thank You this makes a lot of sense!!!! I am currently at a hackathon and it's 3 AM so  I am really glad I got such great responses so quickly. Thanks Again!

Comment: 1. The local utc offset may change between now and the target (an improvement: `time_to_sleep = time.mktime((2015, 5, 25) + (0,)*3 + (-1,)*3) - time.time()` though it also may fail) 2. What happens if the computer hibernates in between? You could sleep `min(HOUR, time_to_sleep)` in a loop until `now >= target` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Of course sleeping for an hour at a time may cause the computer to keep waking up every hour and run out the battery for no good reason, meaning the program never runs. :) These are really just more reasons why you should use an external scheduler instead of trying to do this with `sleep`. :)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: But anyway, I guess you _could_ use aware local datetimes (which will handle DST changes and any already-known timezone changes, as long as your `pytz` library is up-to-date, but it'll still break if your legislature changes your timezone unexpectedly tomorrow), and use platform-specific code to detect sleep/wake and location/TZ changes if you really want to reinvent the _entire_ wheel… but you'd still have the much bigger problem that if someone just reboots the computer your script never runs.

Answer (score -1):

The type is important in Python when you compare two objects

```
date = datetimi.date(2015, 5, 24)
if datetime.date.now().date() == date:
    fromeaddr = ""
```

The `date()` call is there to limit the `datetime` object to its `date` part

Answer (score -2):

You will have to convert your input date variable which is a string to a `datetime` type

something like

```
my_date = raw_input("Give me a date: ")
Give me a date: 24/05/2015

my_date_as_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date, "%d/%m/%Y")

if datetime.date.today() == my_date_as_obj.date():
   # Date matches. Do something
```

Also
Refer : [Datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)
[Strftime](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: He isn't asking for the date as an input, he already has it in a variable. (Plus, he doesn't have it in this format.) So, you showed him how to do something that's irrelevant to his problem, and didn't show him how to do what he actually needs.